# Store a value in database generated from views

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I have a variable computed in my javascript in a view in Grails. Now I wanted to save this value in the database at a corresponding place. How can I do that?
For example: I have the address of the participant and through that I computed the corresponding latitude and longitude. I want to save these in my database.Please tell me how can i do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything yet and can you post some code

I can think of 2 possible ways of doing thing. There is probably more. But I would recommend the first.

1) javascript ajax call using jquery (if you are using prototype or some other javascript framework...there should be something to do this - this is a very common thing)

you will need jquery in your grails app for the following to work.

```
$('#buttonOrSomethingToDriveFunctionCall').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "${createLink(controller: 'user', action: 'saveData')}",
    data: yourDataHere,
    success: function(data) {
        // do something on success
      } 
    });
 });
```

2) would be to write some groovy code in the middle of you view to call the controller directly. This is kind of a bad idea; you will need to do something to save the data to the page and it will make you gsp kind of ugly....Spaghetti code

```
<%@ page import="controllerName" %>

<%
   controllerName->saveData(dataFromjavaScript)

%>
```

Comment: I would go for the Ajax call also. 
I may be "too picky" on this, so you may not care. 

But by default, Ajax issue a "GET" request. 
And this is limited to one thousand something characters of data, and it is not want the HTML standards suggests you should use for non-idempotent request, that is to say, requests that will change the state of your database. 

So I would use the $.post method instead of the $.ajax

Comment: $.post is a shorthand way of using $.ajax for POST requests.There is no big difference between using the two - they are both made possible using the same underlying code. 

$.ajax is generally better to use if you require a greater depth of configuration over your ajax request, if you are only going to be using simple $.post requests in your scripts and applications, post is simpler and easier to use.

also $.post() only supports a success callback, $.ajax() supports beforeSend, success, error and complete callbacks.  I generally prefer to always use $.ajax()

Comment: I get your point. What I should have suggested then is to precise the type of the $.ajax call to POST.